# What is the default phase for tomcat7 maven plugin?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I want my build process to deploy my war to a remote server. until now i have ran `mvn clean install tomcat7:deploy`

This seem wrong to me as it should probably be part of the `deploy` phase. But if I try to do a `mvn deploy` i get:

```
Deployment failed: repository element was not specified in the POM inside distributionManagement element or in -DaltDeploymentRepository=id::layout::url parameter
```

Since I haven't defined any repository to deploy to (I don't really want to deploy to a remote repository, just using this phase to execute the tomcat maven plugin...)

I want to be able to run the tomcat maven plugin without deploying to any remote repository. Is that possible ?

Comment: Please give a reason for the votedown

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The plugin doesn't execute by default. You have to add an execution to it, or call it like you did(f.e. mvn clean install tomcat7:deploy).

The deploy on Tomcat has nothing to do with the Maven deploy phase/deploying to a remote repository.

To bind the Tomcat deployment to a certain phase, add something like this to your tomcat maven plugin configuration:

```
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>tomcat-deploy</id>
      <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>deploy</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
```

In this configuration, the deployment to Tomcat will occur in the pre-integration-test phase, which is the most common phase to do this in I believe.

Comment: I have thought the every plugin in Maven has a default configuration and attaches itself to certain phase. Anyway, pre-integration-test seems like the right phase to put it in...

Comment: Do you happen to know how to deploy this way on an already deployed war ? `redeploy` and `undeploy` goals seems to be missing. the only available ones are `exec-war-only, deploy-only, shutdown, run-war-only, run, deploy, run-war, exec-war, help`

Comment: nevermin. to redeploy you need to add `<update>true</update>` flag to the plugin configuration. http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0-SNAPSHOT/tomcat6-maven-plugin/redeploy-mojo.html

Answer (score 1):

A solution is to bind that to a profile.

```
<profile>
  <id>webapp-deploy</id>
..
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>tomcat-deploy</id>
                <phase>install</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>deploy-only</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
..
</profile>
```

And just run -Pwebapp-deploy

Answer (score 1):

This is because Maven (in a super aggravating decision) decided to co-opt the word "deploy."  In the Maven world, deploy means take your binary you just built and upload it / store it in your local maven repository.  NOT deploy your newly built war to your server.

What most java developers would consider "publishing" an artifact is actually a "deploy" to maven.

It helps if you consider maven as only caring about build with dependency management.  Anything outside of building dependency management requires special calls (like tomcat7:redeploy) or a different scripting environment.